# Making my own grid in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new one in coding, so I expect that this is easy one, but I still can't figure this out.
So I'm trying to make a program that animates a diagram, but the problem is when am making animation with equation (0,0) obviously in upper left corner.
I need to make a grid that will represent this, so I cant input my equation and get right animation depends on this grid's numbers [Grid here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdIqH.png)

UPD:
Sorry for being less specific than I should.
The goal is to make a program that animates HR diagram, outputs luminosity and temperature after you inputs solar mass.
I didn't input equation so far because I'm trying to figure out how pygame animation works.
What I got so far trying to animate diagonal line:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()

width = 600
height = 600


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
background = pygame.image.load("background.png")
point = pygame.image.load("point.png")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
speed = 100

x = 0
y = 0

while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        screen.blit(background, (0,0))
        screen.blit(point, (x,y),)
        milli = clock.tick()
        second = milli/1000.
        dm=second * speed
        x += dm 
        y = x
        print (x, y)

        if x > 600 or y > 600:
            x = 0 
            y = 0


        pygame.display.update()
```

So I need to make axis like in diagram, so I can just type down the equation and make correct animation and correct outputs

Comment: HOW should someone help you? What is your question? What is you code? A nice picture of a grid doesn't help to see what it is all about ... And? Does the answer you have got help you?

Comment: You are drawing an HR diagram here, what are you calculating? If your equations are giving you say B-V colour (for x axis) and L/L_sun for y axis, you can directly plot those by setting axes appropriately. Why do you want to map to a grid?

Comment: @VBB Thank you for your answer. I see you know about the diagram and I have a couple more questions. Can I have your email or something? Thanks

Comment: Easiest to discuss here, so that others can benefit from the answers too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 2 dimensional array to represent a grid structure in python.

```
w, h = 10000, 50000;
grid = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
```